# Fluorescence assays to identify protein concentration without adding a large peptide sequence?

Tags: molecular-biology, proteins, biotechnology, purification

I'm trying to find a way of tagging a protein with something visually quantifiable to track protein concentration through potential purification steps and screen for the most efficient such steps. However, GFP and its cousins are very large proteins that would change the properties I'm targeting for purification, making them non-starters.

Is there a tag that through fluorescence, colorimetrics, etc. can be used to quantify concentration of a single protein while minimally altering chemical/physical properties of the protein for purification?

Comment: It is difficult. There are "[click chemistry](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4241822/)" tools but you would need to find a way to make some modifications on the desired protein in vivo.

Comment: Are small tags an option (FLAG-tag, HA-tag, Myc-tag)?

Comment: @Dr.H.Lecter the tags by themselves are insufficient. You would need an antibody to mark the protein.

Comment: Indeed, but you can generate a fusion protein much faster than creating an specific antibody from scratch. Besides antibodies against the tags I mentionned are commercially available and easy to get.